# Can't delete a file from phone storage in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, file

I am trying to delete a file located at the path

```
"/sdcard/Download/images.jpg"
```

What I've done so far:

```
try{
        File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/images.jpg");
        if(file.exists())
        { deleted = file.delete();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Deleted "+deleted,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Not Deleted "+deleted,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
```

Now I'm getting a toast message:

> File Deleted false

and the file is still at its place(Not deleted :( )
Also I've given android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it Also, never hardcode paths.

Comment: @CommonsWare i didn't find this question even related to mine.

Comment: Put away try ... catch  block and show exception for us.

Comment: You have requested a permission. It is not working. Most likely, that is because you failed to request runtime permissions in an environment that needs them. This is covered in [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636039/115145).

Comment: Do you see any exception?

Comment: I am finding a way to add permissions programmatically because i am working on above API LEVEL 23

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you brother ! your answer worked like a charm. Thanks.